# Same images size and suffix for all iPads?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

In our iPad app we have many assets with no suffix ( `image.png` ) .
Some of them are used by choosing them from the `storyboard` as buttons/backgrounds , and some are used from code .

The storyboard is in `autoLayout` mode .

My question  , how is that i am running the same app for my real `iPad Air`, and than in simulation on the `iPad2/mini` , and in both cases i see the images in the right size, without the needs to supply them in half of their size now(+different suffixes) ?

Is that right to work like that,or may i have problems even though that it works now ?

Now the same assets just works on all iPads versions . did i missed something ?

Comment: So is this image a *retina* image (I.e. 2x scale?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From developer docs of UIImage class method `+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name`

> If the screen has a scale of 2.0, this method first searches for an
>   image file with the same filename with an @2x suffix appended to it.
>   For example, if the file’s name is button, it first searches for
>   button@2x. If it finds a 2x, it loads that image and sets the scale
>   property of the returned UIImage object to 2.0. Otherwise, it loads
>   the unmodified filename and sets the scale property to 1.0.

As far as storyboard is concerned, it shows 1x image in Interface Builder but when app runs on a device, appropriate image gets displayed automatically i.e. 1x on non-retina device & 2x on retina device.

Comment: So basically if using one images set to both devices, that is looks good, can we stay with it ? (the image original size is intended to use for retina, but seems that when he load that same one for non-retina it looks good either . i wonder if we could stick with one images set for both.

Comment: http://support.apparchitect.com/knowledgebase/articles/217819-why-differentiate-between-1x-classic-display-and